# threading issue with armadillo fft2

Tags: c++, multithreading, fft, armadillo

I'm using the armadillo c++ library to do 2D fourier transforms, and I'm finding that the results are inconsistent when I use multiple threads. Specifically, I'm getting different results from the fft2 function.

The data I'm passing to fft2 is thread-local. I've also verified that the input data is not affected by the presence of other threads working on parallel problems. fft2 is producing different results if there are other threads also calling fft2. Does anyone know about threading issues with fft2? Or, armadillo in general?

Answer (score 1):

Armadillo itself does not seem to have any kind of state that could make it not thread-safe (maybe the random generation part could be a problem). That is, it seems to be thread-save as long as the libraries it depends on are thread-safe.

I also had problems in the past with incorrect results when using multithreading. In my case the culprit was openblas, which I was compiling myself. In order to investigate the problem, I had created a [small project](https://github.com/darcamo/test_multithread_openblas) to check that results from some SVD and matrix multiplications were the same when running in parallel and serially. They were not. Then I stumbled into an issue in openblas repository about thread safity, where I saw a flag that I could set in CMake (USE_LOCKING) when compiling openblas. After setting USE_LOCKING to true when compiling openblas I had no more problems with wrong results given by armadillo.

You are probably experience something similar, but regarding the fft2 library. Specially since you mention that other performing work in other threads does not pose a problem if they are not related to fft2. Thus, you should check if fft2 is thread-safe instead of thinking about armadillo.

Comment: Hmm, upon checking I realized that my armadillo was pulling in a default blas library. When I switched to openblas, there was a significant (~40x)  performance boost, but the threading issue persisted. Then, I saw that openblas has a compile option 'pthread'. I recompiled openblas with the pthread enabled, but no luck. When you say that you compiled openblas yourself, you mean that you downloaded the source code and then edited the CMake file by hand? That's a little messy, but it's starting to look like that may be necessary.

Comment: I mentioned openblas to make a point that the threading issue is not in armadillo directly but in its dependencies. During my investigations, if I had observed that I had no issues if I used the system openblas (Arch Linux). In your case, I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the FFT library, which is probably not thread safe.